# Laravel join multiple tables to get data

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, laravel

In my scenario i have 3 tables. customers, services and services_info.

**customers table**:

id | firstname | lastname ..etc.

**services table**:

id | service_id

**services_info**:

id | category | service | estimated_time

I want to get customers services information joining these tables. A customer has many services. so i created customer_service table with foreign keys to customer table and services table, but it has services ids only, services information is in service_info table. How can i join these tables to get each customers service information ? I'm using laravel 5.8 and i'm new to it. help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: it stores customer services, one customer can have multiple services. it stores separately in this table. is there any proper way ?

Comment: yes you can try this way below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `customer_has_services` table

```
id|customer_id|service_id|created_at|updated_at
```

app/Models/Customer.php:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Models;
     
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Models\Service;
     
    class Customer extends Model {
        ...
        public function services() {
            return $this->belongsToMany( Service::class, "customer_has_services ", "sevice_id", "customer_id" );
        }
    }
?>
```

app/Models/Service.php:

```
<?php
 
    namespace App\Models;
     
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Models\Customer;
     
    class Service extends Model {
        ...
        public function customers() {
            return $this->belongsToMany( Customer::class, "customer_has_services ", "customer_id", "sevice_id" );
        }
        /**
         * Get the phone associated with the user.
         */
        public function info() {
            return $this->hasOne( ServiceInfo::class, "id", "service_id" );
        }
    }
?>
```

app/Http/Controllers/CustomerController.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\Customer;

    class CustomerController extends Controller {
        public function index() {
            $customers = Customer::with( "services.info" )->get();
            foreach( $customers as $customer ) {
                foreach( $customer[ "services" ] as $service ) {
                    echo $service[ "info" ][ "sevice" ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships.

Customers and services should be many to many.
Services and service info should be one to one.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 9, maybe has some error.